# C++ implementation of quicksort with iterators (unstable sorting)

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel, template, iterator, quick-sort

Please review the following quicksort implementation.
`qsort` below is intentionally unstable, as `partition` reoders equal elements.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

// Ensures pivot is at position end.
template<typename Iter, typename T>
Iter part_pivot(Iter begin, Iter end, T pivot) {
  while (begin != end) {
    if (*begin < pivot)
      ++begin;
    else if (*--end < pivot)
      iter_swap(begin, end);
  }
  return begin;
}

template<typename Iter>
Iter part(Iter begin, Iter end) {
  typename iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type pivot = *begin;
  Iter mid = part_pivot(begin, end, pivot);
  // Ensure pivot is at position mid.
  iter_swap(--end, mid);
  return mid;
}

template<class Iter>
void quicksort(Iter begin, Iter end) {
  if (std::distance(begin, end) < 2)
    return;
  Iter mid = part(begin, end, *begin);
  quicksort(begin, mid);
  quicksort(++mid, end);
}

template<class T>
void quicksort(vector<T>& v) {
  quicksort(v.begin(), v.end());
}

template <class T>
void print(const vector<T>& v) {
  for (const T& t : v)
    cout << t << " ";
  cout << endl;
}

int main() {
  vector<int> v = {1,4,8,34,2,3,45,6,87,4,3};
  print(v);
  quicksort(v);
  print(v);
}
```

Comment: Probably shouldn't use the same names as functions in the standard library, unless yours are in a different namespace (and even then, I'm not sure reusing `qsort` is advisable. It isn't that great of a name unless you're using a 1970s-era compiler that limited identifier names to 6–8 characters.) Speaking of the standard library, why aren't you just using `std::sort`? That makes it hard to review the code: since you are including `<algorithm>`, I'd want to recommend using, *e.g.*, `std::swap`, but then the existence of `std::sort` makes the whole exercise rather silly.

Comment: Your sort recurses infinitely at `qsort(mid, end);` for me.

Comment: I've updated the code, addressing both of your comments, @CodyGray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems with the code that I see immediately:

1. `if (std::distance(begin, end) <= 2)` is wrong since it leaves an array like {2,1} untouched. This means that the code can screw up every time it recurses to an array of size 2.
2. `Iter partition(Iter begin, Iter end, const T& pivot)`: Passing pivot as `const T&` is a bad idea. When passed as const reference, when you perform the iter_swap, the value pointed to by begin changes and so does pivot. Hence running your code gives me a segfault but changing const T& to T takes care of the segfault.

Even if these are fixed, there is something more subtle. Suppose you try to sort an already sorted array like {1,1,1}. Partitioning this will return `mid = begin`. So unless you make an explicit check for a sorted array you will recurse infinitely on `qsort(mid,end)`.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. 1 + 2 are easy to fix. The subtle non-termination bug occurs because `partition` neither places the pivot in the middle, nor always returns an iterator that is strictly inside the given interval. I'll see what the easiest fix is.

Comment: I've updated the code, care to take a look again?

Comment: I don't think it is good practice to update question and code after accepting an answer, it would have been better to ask as a new question. In any case, have you tested the code on simple vectors to see if they work?